# What can be done to prevent questions that aren't answered right away from never getting any answers?

Tags: discussion

I get good response to most of the questions I ask on Stack Overflow.

But some of the questions I ask get a little bit traffic right away, but after they've left the front screen of newest answers, it seems they never get noticed again.

What can be done to prevent answers from never getting answered by anyone? Maybe there should be a little bonus for answering year-old questions?

Comment: You mean like the [`Revival`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/126/revival) and [`Necromancer`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer) badges?

Comment: The [necromancer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer) badge exists for this reason.

Comment: When there's nothing interesting in the front-page, I use to dig the archives for good Questions. Maybe the OP already solved it, but hey, things here are not primarily about the OP ;)